# Angular2 Http POST header argument type error

Tags: angular, http, header

This service should perform a HTTP post request to my PHP backend api, but ng2 won't compile the project, it throws the following error:

> ERROR in login-service.ts (25,9): Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
>     Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>         Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'.

My snippet looks like:

```
import { HttpModule }     from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http }           from '@angular/http';
import { Response }       from '@angular/http';
import { Headers }        from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }
  login(username, password){
    var body = 'foo=bar&foo1=bar1';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http
    .post('http://127.0.0.1/server.php', body, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe((data:Response) => {
       let res = data.text();
       console.log('Result: ',res);
     }, error => {
       console.log('Error: ', JSON.stringify(error.json()));
     });
  }
}
```

This code works perfectly in a different ng2 app.

Comment: The error text shows the header value as `Headers` with a capital H, but your code sample shows `headers` with a small h.  Please make sure you reproduce the code and the error accurately.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, adding Headers to the imports did the trick (thanks  Subtain Ishfaq)

import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";

Answer (score 2):

You have to use:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

Updated Login Method:

```
 login(username, password){
    var body = 'foo=bar&foo1=bar1';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http
    .post('http://127.0.0.1/server.php', body, options)
    .subscribe((data:Response) => {
       let res = data.text();
       console.log('Result: ',res);
     }, error => {
       console.log('Error: ', JSON.stringify(error.json()));
     });
  }
```

Comment: @Haarvey check you imports , The Headers type you are supposed to import is `import {Headers} from '@angular/http' `;.

Comment: If this answer helped you, accept and let me know if you need any further help.